# Control DC Motor with Micrcontroller

Tags: motor, dc

I would like to use a microcontroller to control when a pump turns on and off. I will use a 12 volt battery to supply both the dc motor for the pump and microcontroller. How can I interface the microcontroller with the dc motor?

Thank you stackexchange community

Comment: Use a H bridge or a single MOSFET with back emf protection diode. Armed with that info, you will find google is your new best friend.

Comment: You will need to know how much current the pump draws (running and stalled) be able to design this.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a switch that you don't need to flip frequently, the simplest way to control the power to your pump is by using a relay.

The microcontroller will drive the on/off state of the relay, and the relay will serve as an on/off switch between your 12V battery and the pump.

Comment: You have to make sure the MCU can source enough current to toggle the relay.

Comment: And don't forget the snubber to protect the micro's output.